# I need to run a specific python module which only works on a Linux device but I have a Windows laptop. What's my best option?

Tags: python

At university I have been working on Linux machines writing various Python scripts. A specific python module (PyEphem) that I have been running all term only works on Linux devices but I'm home for the holidays and need to run my code. Unfortunately I only have access to a 64-bit Windows laptop.

What's the best quick fix to be able to run Linux? I've been reading about downloading a virtual machine or using a duel boot OS on my laptop or running Linux straight from a USB / SD card?

What's my best option?

Comment: The [PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) website mentions Windows support repeatedly. Have you tried just using Windows?

Comment: You can run it in a [Docker](https://dev.to/grahamlyons/the-quickest-way-to-run-python-in-docker-165) or [Vagrant](https://codingnetworker.com/2015/09/use-vagrant-to-run-the-python-examples/) thin hypervisors, or you can go out an just install a *nix flavor of your choice in a VM under [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and run it there.

Comment: If your laptop runs Windows 10, check out the Windows Subsystem for Linux, (or whatever the official name is).

Answer (score 1):

If your programs don't require a large amount of processing power, I'd go with a bootable copy of Linux on a USB stick. Note that unless you make the memory persistent (see link) then every time you boot the usb it will start without any of your programs installed and you would have to install them again.

In my experience, getting your computer to dual-boot just so you can work on Linux for a few weeks is not a good idea because once you partition the hard drive and do you work, the computer stays partitioned unless you go through the work of undoing the partition which is a pain.

Try reading this: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: Does Ubuntu still come with Wubi? If so, you can dual-boot your windows machine without having to repartition your hard drive.

Comment: Apparently it has become discontinued https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(software). There is a project on github that has kept it going though https://www.lifewire.com/wubi-linux-installation-program-2201175

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to get around without dual boot and VM  just install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html)

from wiki

> Cygwin is a Unix-like environment and command-line interface for
>   Microsoft Windows. Cygwin provides native integration of Windows-based
>   applications, data, and other system resources with applications,
>   software tools, and data of the Unix-like environment.

another one

[Gow (Gnu On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)

and lite one
[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)